# MovingPlatform - move position1 to position2 then wait for 3 sec

Tags: unity, c#

I have one PlatformManager (Script Attached)

One is Position-1

One is Position-2

One is MovingPlatform

I want. MovingPlatform move Position-1 to Position-2 then wait for 5 Sec

then MovingPlatform move Position-2 to Position-1 then wait for 5 Sec

**Here is code for PlatformManager & its working fine without Wait**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        ChangeTarget();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
    }
}
```

**I have tried this code but MovingPlatform didnt Wait**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestMovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Also i tried This but not success**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestMovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Transform position3;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Here i attached Screenshot of Hirerchy & Inspector
[image: Here i attached Screenshot of Hirerchy & Inspector]

Also i tried other different MovingPlatform Scripts but MovingPlatform's movement is jerky when player ride on it.

Only this script. MovingPlatform's movement is smooth when Player ride on it.
So, I used this string script.

Anyone idea how to solve this?

Comment: You could simply use a while loop containing all the code inside your coroutine and have it wait for any amount to time you need by `yield return new WaitForSeconds(time)`

Answer (score -1):

Call your co routine only once instead

```
 void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
 }

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
}
IEnumerator ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        } 
        yield return null;
      StopCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
     StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());

    }
```

Comment: The coroutine is being called twice in your code, so your commentary doesn't match. The important bit here is to *not use Invoke* as the invoke discards the resting IEnumerator that would have otherwise been used for the coroutine scheduling.

Comment: i tried your answer. but still problem exists.